How to preserve Markdown whitespace inside JSX?
I need to preserve the formatting inside TSX (TypeScript JSX) element exactly as it is. I don't use React, it's later rendered with custom JSX Element implementation.
<markdown>
  Line 1
  Line 2

  Line 3

  - a
  - b
</markdown>

But, it won't work, both the bun run play.jsx and the tsc the TypeScript compiler strip whitespaces and convert it to:
<markdown>Line 1 Line 2 Line 3 - a - b</markdown>

As far as understand there's no standard way to do that. Any hacky way to make it work with bun or tsc (TypeScript compiler)?
